# Adding a function to prototype

Tags: javascript, prototype

I try to implement the Vector3 class in JS and wrote

```
function Vector(x,y,z) {
  this.x=x;
  this.y=y;
  this.z=z;
}
```

so far looks alright, but then I wanted to add the `Vector.prototype` the function `addVector`:

```
Vector.prototype.addVector(addx,addy,addz) = function(addx,addy,addz) {
  x+=addx; y+=addy; z+=addz;
};
```

but then I receive an error:

> ReferenceError at line NaN: addx is not defined

I'm new to JS and I wonder what exactly I'm mistyping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several correct answers already but let me expand on them for you with a simple visual example so you can learn; it seems you may be unfamiliar with JavaScript prototypes.

```
// Here is a new function or in this case class
function Person() {};

// This is one way we could add methods to the Person() class
// After you call this method Person() will now have firstName,
// lastName, and age properties
Person.prototype.recordInfo = function(fname,lname,age){
    this.firstName = fname;
    this.lastName = lname;
    this.age = age;
}
```

If you wan't to keep things together a bit more and have a lot of methods you'll be adding to the Person() class you can also declare your methods like so:

```
Person.prototype = {
    recordInfo: function(fname,lname,age){
        this.firstName = fname;
        this.lastName = lname;
        this.age = age;
    },
    aNewMethod: function(){
        // ...
    }, 
    bNewMethod: function(){
        // ...
    }
}; // <-- Notice the closing semicolon and the commas separating the methods above
```

Comment: @user2956754 to mark an answer as accepted you click on the check mark beside the answer your choosing. It will turn from greyed out to filled in.

Answer (score 8):

Replace:

```
Vector.prototype.addVector(addx,addy,addz) =
```

With:

```
Vector.prototype.addVector =
```

That's not where you specify the parameters.

Comment: thanks
i tried
Vector.prototype.addVector) = function(addx,addy,addz){
 this.x+=addx; this.y+=addy; this.z+=addz;};

but missed out that i should not have () at all.

Comment: So, that fixes your problem then, @user2956754?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the syntax. The following should do your job.

```
Vector.prototype.addVector = function(addx,addy,addz){
    x+=addx;
    y+=addy;
    z+=addz;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct your syntax

```
Vector.prototype.addVector = function (addx, addy, addz) {
this.x+=addx;
this.y+=addy;
this.z+=addz;
}
```

check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) for reading more about prototypes.